# How to find first link and wrap entire div in its href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I would like to use JavaScript to find the first link in a `div` (the learn more link) and wrap the entire `div` with that href dynamically.

How can I revise this code so it does this?

```js
$('div.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC').wrap("<a href=''></a>", function() {
  a.href = $('a:first', this).attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dnn_pane02textLeft" class="flexPane LeftPane textPane">
  <div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-499 DnnVersionableControl">
    <a name="499"></a>
    <div id="dnn_ctr499_ContentPane" style="background-color:#f2a42a;">
      <div id="dnn_ctr499_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
        <div id="dnn_ctr499_HtmlModule_lblContent">
          <h1>Analytic Solutions</h1>
          <p>Wilshire serves the investment analytic needs of institutional investors by offering a platform that combines the depth of our capabilities within...
          </p>
          <h5><a href="/analytics/analytic-solutions/">Learn More</a></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add the relevant code in the question - don't expect us to go outside of SO to see it.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Since when, JS fiddle external links have always been used on SO? I have added the code @Andy

Comment: They have, but always accompanied by code - if jsfiddle is not available your question is worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the element and remove the text content then wrap by it

```js
$('div.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC').wrap(function() {
  return $('a:first', this).clone().text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dnn_pane02textLeft" class="flexPane LeftPane textPane">
  <div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-499 DnnVersionableControl">
    <a name="499"></a>
    <div id="dnn_ctr499_ContentPane" style="background-color:#f2a42a;">
      <div id="dnn_ctr499_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
        <div id="dnn_ctr499_HtmlModule_lblContent">
          <h1>Analytic Solutions</h1>
          <p>Wilshire serves the investment analytic needs of institutional investors by offering a platform that combines the depth of our capabilities within...
          </p>
          <h5><a href="/analytics/analytic-solutions/">Learn More</a></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or by creating new a tag

```js
$('div.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC').wrap(function() {
  return $("<a/>", {
    href: $('a:first', this).attr('href')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dnn_pane02textLeft" class="flexPane LeftPane textPane">
  <div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-499 DnnVersionableControl">
    <a name="499"></a>
    <div id="dnn_ctr499_ContentPane" style="background-color:#f2a42a;">
      <div id="dnn_ctr499_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
        <div id="dnn_ctr499_HtmlModule_lblContent">
          <h1>Analytic Solutions</h1>
          <p>Wilshire serves the investment analytic needs of institutional investors by offering a platform that combines the depth of our capabilities within...
          </p>
          <h5><a href="/analytics/analytic-solutions/">Learn More</a></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Could I then use JS to remove the href IF the div also has class .RadAjaxPanel (div.RadAjaxPanel.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC)? The reason is in DotNetNuke admin you need to click the box to edit it, and clicking it would go to that url. The admin view adds that class to the div though. Apologies if I need to ask a new question.

Comment: For the same .ModDNNHTMLC div but only if it's parent has .RadAjaxPanel. so: "div.RadAjaxPanel.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC" - @PranavCBalan

Comment: Add an if condition and check the parent has that class in following format `if(this).parent().hasClass('RadAjaxPanel')){.......}`

Comment: $('div.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC').wrap(function() {
      return $('a:first', this).clone().text('');
      if(this).parent().hasClass('RadAjaxPanel')) {
         $(this).removeAttr("href");
      }
 });

Comment: @KevinOrin not like that...... `$('div.textPane .DNNModuleContent.ModDNNHTMLC').wrap(function() { return $('a:first', this).clone().text('').attr('href',function(i,v){return $(this).parent().hasClass('RadAjaxPanel')?'':v;});  });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110759/discussion-between-kevinorin-and-pranav-c-balan).